# How to destroy() my popup correctly in Sencha Touch

Tags: popup, sencha-touch, extjs, destroy

I am having difficulties implementing the destroy method on my popup. Everything works fine, the below code works for having one popup that changes its contents depending what is clicked on. But I notice that my content (media) still plays when hiding the popup. I'd like to destroy it completely, and re-create on click. I've not really found anything in the forums that helps me achieve this, so I think it will help others too :-)

There are a couple of things confusing me, as there is already a click listener on the markers, which initiates the popup, where should I put the destroy code? Should I be declaring it as a separate function outside the popup, then calling it on beforehide somehow?

```
function addMarker(country) 
        {
    if (true) 
            {
      var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(country.image48Path);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map.map,
        title: country.title,
        position: country.position,
        //draggable: true,
        icon:image
      });


      var goToCountryWrapper = function (button, event)
                {
                    goToCountry(country, this.popup);
      };


      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() 
                {
        if (!this.popup) 
                    {  ---> Should I be placing destroy code here?
          this.popup = new Ext.Panel(
                            {
            floating: true,
            modal: true,
            centered: true,
            width: 800,
            height: 600,
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            scroll: 'vertical',
            items:[(new countryOverlay(country)).overlayPanel,
            {
              xtype:'button', 
              margin: 20,
              ui:'action-round',
              text:'Click here to view more promo videos',
              handler:goToCountryWrapper,
              scope : this
            },],
                layout: {
              type: 'auto',
              padding: '55',
              align: 'left'
            },
            dockedItems: [{
              dock: 'top',
              xtype: 'toolbar',
              ui: 'light',
              title: country.title
              }],
    ---> Should I be placing a listener here for beforehide, destroying here?
          });
        };
        this.popup.show('pop');

      });    
    }
  };

---> Should I be placing the destroy code after, as a seperate function?
```

Thanks,

Digeridoopoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you want to destroy it when you hide the popup? If so, you should listen tot he hide event and then destroy it then.

```
this.popup.on('hide', function() {
    this.popup.destroy();
}, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
             hideOnMaskTap:true,
                    listeners : {
                        hide: function() {
                          this.destroy();
                          }
                    },
```